# Copy an object that can't implement Copy

Tags: rust

I have this section of code where I need to figure out the type of an encoded value and I don't know if it is a String, an unsigned integer, or a Vector of String. I thought of doing the following:

```
while let Some(pair) = dict_dec.next_pair()? {
    match pair {
    ...
    // &[u8]      Object<'_, '_>
    (unknown_field, value) => {
        let field_name = String::from_utf8_lossy(unknown_field).to_string();
        let value_as_string: String = match String::decode_bencode_object(value) {
            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(_) => match u64::decode_bencode_object(value) {
                Ok(u) => u.to_string(),
                Err(_) => match Vec::<String>::decode_bencode_object(value) {
                    Ok(v) => v.join(", "),
                    Err(_) => "Unknown value".to_string(),
                    },
                },
            };
                
        let tuple: (String, String) = (field_name, value_as_string);
        ......

    }
}
```

However `value` from the bendy crate can't implement Copy, it is moved after calling `decode_bencode_object`, and `decode_bencode_object` doesn't take a reference. Is there a way I can call it multiple times, make a copy or a different approach that would let me get the same result?

Comment: I have no idea what this complex decoding scheme has to do with copying, but to answer the title question, `u32`, `String`, and `Vector<String>` all implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), which means you can call `.clone()` to copy them. The call has to be explicit, since copying vectors and strings is more complex than a mere bitcopy, so Rust doesn't want it happening behind-the-scenes.

Comment: I am not trying to copy a u32, a String or a Vector, but the variable value that I use as an argument for decode_bencode_object. value is an object from the bendy crate and doesn't implement copy, however I want to pass it three times as an argument to try to decode it as a String, as a int, or as a Vector.

Comment: I think it would help to edit your question to include the full error message you saw when you tried this, and information about which library this `decode_bencode_object` function belongs to, so it's clearer what the problem is and what the constraints on the solution might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inferring from your question that you are using [the `FromBencode` trait from crate `bendy`](https://docs.rs/bendy/0.3.3/bendy/decoding/trait.FromBencode.html) and so therefore these values are of type [`Object`](https://docs.rs/bendy/0.3.3/bendy/decoding/enum.Object.html). Since `FromBencode` takes ownership of the `Object` it's given, you cannot continue to use `value` after you've passed it to one type's implementation of this trait.

The smallest change from your current program would be to call the `clone` method to create a deep copy of your `Object` for each call to `decode_bencode_object`. That would mean that you'd be moving the copy into the method and so you'd retain ownership of the original object. However, you will need to pay the cost of cloning the `Object` value potentially multiple times, so you should consider whether that cost is acceptable for your use-case.

Another possibility would be to decide which type to try before you call the trait method. I'm not familiar with this library so I'm guessing a little but it seems like you could make some inferences based on which variant of `enum Object` is selected, like this:

```
match &value {
    Object::Bytes(_) => {
        // use String::decode_bencode_object
    }
    Object::Integer(_) => {
        // use u64::decode_bencode_object
    }
    Object::List(_) => {
        // use Vec::<String>::decode_bencode_object
    }
}
```

The `match` expression uses a borrow of `value` so that you can retain ownership of it for use inside each of the three match arms. Each arm only needs to call one `decode_bencode_object` method, so this should be acceptable as long as you don't try to use `value` again after the `match` block.